# Python script.py once saved now won't load as before

Tags: python-2.7, terminal

I have just started looking & learning Python (on Ubuntu 14.04) using the website: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ and http://www.codecademy.com/

Yesterday, I worked for an hour on a few scripts namely 1-4 and named them as ex1.py etc and they executed fine. Today, I have come back to carry on with a few more exercises and tested my first exercises only to find now I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when attempting  "python ex1.py" with or without .py  I have tried "#!/usr/bin/python" in any script header also. The path/Dir I have been using to test my Python scripts in is simply 'Python' within my Home Dir. I checked the actual file permissions but that appears to make no difference.

I am not too sure if it's an OS setup issue; Python issue; or simply me. Python seems great, so any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  What has changed since yesterday to my python.py script files?

Comment: What happens when you type python -V in the terminal? Also, it would be useful if you could post `ext1.py` if it's not too long.

Comment: What happens when you type python -V in the terminal?: I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined   The exercise is taken from the online book first one being: #!/usr/bin/python

print "Hello World!"
print "hello Again"
print "I like typing this."
print "This is fun."
print 'yay! Printing.'
print "I'd much rather you 'not'."
print 'I "said" do not touch this.'
print "Hey Paul, I printed another line!"

typing at Terminal python -v gave me a longer response may I add! (-:

Comment: Okay, I have a hunch as to what it might be. What does the command prompt look like? >>>?

Comment: After running $python at the Terminal Command, it is the >>> style when in Python. I'm on Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are in the Python interpreter, and not the Linux terminal. This is indicated both by the error messages you saw and by the >>> prompt.

Exit the interpreter by holding down control and pressing the D key. You will then be back in the Linux terminal and running a script will work the way you expect it to.

Comment: Yes, @dandan78 you are correct! that works fine a silly mistake on my part (-: Obviously I was entering text in Gedit, saving and running. Assuming I was in my /Python Dir (which Iwsn't I then had to CD Python   DIR), it all works well know. Quite embarrassing! LOL Still, we have to learn somewhere. I wouldn't mind, I do know the Unix DIR commands. Still thank you all the same for taking time out of your day to help. I'll mark it as 'correct'. Peace.

Comment: Future Users: Lesson learned, make sure you are in your working DIR (in my case /python is where my test_example.py files are) and run in TERMINAL NOT the Python Interpreter which was where I was going initially wrong.

Comment: No problem, @PaulB, glad the issue has been sorted out.